# Is the register by the U.S. Patent and Trademark Office seachable by the public?

Tags: trademark

Is it possible to review the data base of existing marks beforehand?

Or must one assume the government's data base is in perfectly good order?

Comment: Trademarks are different from copyrights, much as doors are different from windows, even though both let things into a house. Many trademarks are not protectable at all by copyright, although some logos are. The term "copyright" should not be used for a trademark, or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you. You are saying here that there is a principle register for trademarks and a different principle register for copyrights? Please confirm so I can learn how this works.

Comment: There is a copyright register for the US (there is no secondary register), but it is very different from the trademark register. Most major trademarks are registered, because full protection requires registration. For copyrights, the main benefit of registration is the availability of statutory damages and attorney fees in a lawsuit. In practice, most commercial publications and few others are registered. Note that this comment is protected by copyright, but no one would ever register such a brief text with no commercial value.

Comment: US copyright is different from other copyright laws to a significantly greater extent than US trademark law is from the trademark laws of other countries. The US Copyright office issues Circular 1: ["Copyright Basics"](https://www.Copyright.gov/circs/circ01.pdf) that explains much of US copyright law. Copyright law, unlike trademark law, has direct constitutional authority. Trademark law is covered by the power to regulate interstate and foreign commerce.

Comment: @David Siegel Thank you for your helpful comments. Before paying good money to register something, I would want to be sure that any data base maintained by the government is well-maintained and not a muddle after so many years. Is there an independent audit of the registry? ...so potential applicants could be confident that the register is in good shape and can not be changed somewhere along the line.

Comment: I don't know if the registry is audited, either internally or externally. But I think a person wantign to register a trademark in the US has little choice but to use it. It should not, however, be the only search an applicant does. The various US states maintain separate trademark registries. And since marks in active use but never registered can cause a US registration to be denied, a search for actual business names similar to the proposed mark is a good idea, I understand. These complexities are why many hire pros for this process.

Comment: I understand the first question. I'm not quite sure what is intended by the second question: "Or must one assume the government's data base is in perfectly good order?"

Comment: @David Siegel But how to trust the good-will and/or competency of a pro? Seems that people will do anything for money and ethical standards do not exist in practice. Just because a pro charges me five hundred or five thousand dollars, how could one know he or she ever did an exhaustive search?

Comment: @Maria Alaniz If the pro claims to have done an exhaustive search, and there is later a conflicting mark found that such a search would have/should have turned up, the pro's reputation will be damages, and the pro may be liable for damages.  Also one can consult former user's of the pro's services. Some pros in various fields may be dishonest, but IME most are not. Those with more resources may have advantages in legal affairs, but often the law will support the rights of less privileged people.

Comment: @ohwilleke A  database can be corrupted over tiem in various ways. data entry may be done carelessly, or updates may not be made when they should be. Poor design may allow concurrent updates to the same record that leave corrupted data.  Replication and backup/restore operations may have errors causeing lost or mismatched data. I think this sort of thing is what the OP means by "not in perfectly good order"

Comment: @David Siegel How to trust the good-will and/or competency of a pro? Seems that people will do anything for money and ethical standards do not exist in practice. Just because a pro charges me five hundred or five thousand dollars, how could one know he or she ever did anything like an exhaustive search? No disrespect intended. I can't help but wonder if the government workers who input to the data base do a good job, because maintaining such a data base would be a formidable job.

Comment: " one can consult former user's of the pro's services" How would one go about this?
Thank you for your detailed and forthright replies to my questions. I hope they are not impertinent.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz Maintaining the database is a ministerial job. The entires in the database simply involve putting what was on approved trademark applications into the database (often in an automated process). But when you pay a pro to do a search, that isn't restricted to federal government patent and trademark office databases. It also includes a search of state databases and of non-governmental sources. A trademark can be established and valid even if it isn't in a government database and isn't registered. This is why trademark searches cost so much money.

Comment: @Maria Alaniz Ine asks for referrals, for evidence of past successful operations. One looks at length of service. One searches for public complaints. One looks at online ratings. If possible, one asks other pros in the same field. Perhaps, one can get a contract with a money-back guarantee or a partial guarantee.  For searches in particular, one can ask for records of searches done and results found. And one must evaluate the personality as one would do any person one is considering trusting in a business deal.

Comment: Also worth noting that searching the patent database is much harder than searching the trademark database, because the indexing process for patents is intrinsically less comprehensive. In other words, there are more ways to characterize equivalent patents than there are to characterize equivalent trademarks.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks again to  you and Mr. David for the frank and informative explanations. I am a novice and do not know for sure what I am talking about. People tell us we should register our jewelry designs. That is not a copyright. Not a patent. What is the government register where jewelry design is afforded a legal quality of some kind? What is that register called? Do you know?

Answer (score 3):

The register of trademarks can indeed be searched before an application is filed, and any prudent applicant will make, or pay an expert to make, such a search.

Note that each country has its own trademark register (although some EU countries are working on a shared EU register, I understand). Marks registered in one country will not be protected under the laws of another, unless they separately qualify for protection under the laws of the second country.

Note that in the US, marks that have never been registered but are in active use receive some trade mark protection, although not as much as those that have been registered. Searching for unregistered marks in current use is significantly harder than searching for registered marks. Application may be refused for conflict with an active, unregistered mark.

Also in the US, registered marks may have their registrations canceled if they are not in use for a significant time, I believe at least 5 years.

Many advise hiring a firm that specializes in trademark applications to do the entire application, including searches. This involves significant added cost.

US trademark searches may be done via the [Trademark Electronic Search System (TESS)](https://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=login&p_lang=english&p_d=trmk)

Some information about doing such searches is provided at [Search trademark database](https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/search) (an official USPTO page). That page states:

> **Private trademark attorneys**
>
> If you are an applicant, registrant, or party to Trademark Trial and Appeal Board proceedings domiciled in the United States or its territories, you are not required to have a U.S.-licensed attorney represent you at the USPTO. However, deciding what to search for and interpreting your results can be complicated. There are many factors to consider in determining likelihood of confusion. We can’t advise you on how to do a clearance search for your mark, do one for you, or interpret your search results. Therefore, we strongly encourage you to hire a U.S.-licensed attorney who specializes in trademark law to guide you throughout the application process.
>
> If you are a foreign-domiciled applicant, registrant, or party to Trademark Trial and Appeal Board proceedings, you must be represented at the USPTO by an attorney who is licensed to practice law in the United States.
>
> See the why hire a private trademark attorney webpage to learn more about what an attorney can do for you and how to find one.
>
> For more information about conducting a clearance search, please watch the news broadcast-style video titled “Searching” (video #3 in the Trademark Information Network (TMIN) series).

I am sure that similar searches of the register in other countries are available.

Comment: Thank you. I will review the linked-to materials, before commenting further.